# how to see the results of C++ code (developed for a dll file)

Tags: c++, variables, debugging, visual-studio-code, dll

I am working on a c++ project which gives me a dll file. Then I will add that dll file as a plugin file to use in other software.
The problem here is that I can not see the errors in my c++ code until I run the dll code in the software.
If I could run the C++ code in the visual studio, for some particular input values, then I can easily find where are my errors. [image]
Here in the above picture, for example, I have defined a tensor and tried to find the variables defined after double. how can I see the results of these variables in C++? (visual studio)

Comment: *The problem here is that I can not see the errors in my c++ code until I run the dll code in the software* -- Create an `int main()` and call your function(s) from there.

Comment: Read up on unit testing.

Comment: You should have a test harness.  Maybe create your own DLL, call it "TestDLL" and use it for testing.  Doing that, you will not only test your code, you test the plugin system, which could also be a point of failure.

Comment: Usual method for that is, as already said, a minimal executable that loads properly the DLL (i.e. with EXACT same mechanism as the real program), and once loaded, you launch a test sequence - ideally, all functions should be tested for all execution branches including known error cases and for "good" values for each parameter, so minimal value, maximal value, special values (like zero, empty containers/strings, `nullptr` for pointers, ...), using combinaison to get a proper and meaningful test.